# The shortest way to convert infix expressions to postfix (RPN) in C

Tags: c

Original formulation is given [here](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ONP/) (you can try also your program for correctness) .

Additional rules:
 1. The program should read from standard input and write to standard output.
 2. The program should return zero to the calling system/program.
 3. The program should compile and run with gcc -O2 -lm -s -fomit-frame-pointer.

The challenge has some history: the call for short implementations has been announced at the [Polish programming contest blog](http://contest.pl/2009/09/12/konkurs-najkrotszy-kod-2/) in September 2009. After the contest, the shortest code was 81 chars long. Later on the second call has been made for even shorter code and after the year matix2267 [published his solution](http://contest.pl/2009/10/19/konkurs-najkrotszy-kod-3/#comment-483) in 78 bytes:

```
main(c){read(0,&c,1)?c-41&&main(c-40&&(c%96<27||main(c),putchar(c))):exit(0);}
```

Anyone to make it even shorter or prove this is impossible?

Comment: @fuzzyTew, short circuit is not undefined for c it is actually very well defined. || and && are supposed to short circuit

Comment: apologies for deleting
I did experience that visual studio 6 with optimizations enabled would reverse their order.  must have been one of its many bugs.

Comment: I don't vote to close. I vote to delete tag [code-golf].

Comment: Is it just me, or is that code unreadable? I can't figure out what the heck it's doing...

Comment: @Lamber please have a look at the explanation written by mizo to his code (might be helpful to understand this one).

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5839/2775

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a way to reduce the code down to **76** chars:

```
main(c){read(0,&c,1)?c-41&&main(c-40&&putchar(c,c%96>26&&main(c))):exit(0);}
```

A longer, commented version for clarity:

```
int main(int c)
{
   if (read(0,&c,1)) {          /* read char */
       if (c-41) {              /* if not ')' */
           if (c-40) {          /* then if not '(' */
               if (c%96>26) {   /* then if operator (not alphabet or <LF>) */
                   main(c);     /* recurse */
               }
               putchar(c);      /* print */
           }
           main(c);             /* recurse */
       }        
   } else exit(0);              /* end program */
}
```

Comment: @Chris Dodd  any example/explanation?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not out to break any records but I'll post this anyway:

```
#define x(z) while(p>##z s)putchar(*p--);
main(c){
int s[9],*p=s-1;
for(;read(0,&c,1);){
isalpha(c)?putchar(c):c=='('?(c=0):c==')'?(c=1):isdigit(c)?:(*++p=c);
if(c==0){x()main(0);}
if(c==1) break;}
x(=)return 0;}
```

**Edit:** Fixed correctness issues pointed out by kuszi's comment.

Comment: If you like this sort of puzzles You can have a look at [this contest](http://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/) for more (variety of programming languages allowed).

Comment: Your program should not output the number of test cases, and it lacks the new line character after the test case. See [the working example](http://ideone.com/ihrpz)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the real winner is the one who wrote this small code you provided, but you can slightly modify it to remove the exit:

```
main(c){read(0,&c,1)?c-41&&main(c-40&&(c%96<27||main(c),putchar(c))):0;}
```

I tried and it works.

Comment: Was going to agree, but I tried it out and the result was almost the same but not quite. Using the example input from http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ONP/ you get an extra trailing "3".

Comment: I don't have this extra "3" with gcc 3.4.4. Which one are you using?

Comment: gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11). That said, I tried it out on gcc 4.1.2 and it works just fine.

Comment: OK it seems it depends on the version of gcc. Not sure it is worth a downvote, but that means it is not a good solution. I am surprised different versions of gcc are providing different results by the way.

Comment: I agree, it's definitely not worth a downvote. If anything, it highlights the issue of code portability. +1 for a good attempt.

Comment: @Benoit, as I understand, the program interprets the numbers on first line of input as operators. When input runs out, a matching number of actual operators and operands has been printed. The "stray" number should still be in the recursion tree, unprinted, when `exit(0)` kills the whole program. If `exit` doesn't happen, execution happily climbs down the recursion tree and prints all remaining characters on its way. Are you sure the stray `3` isn't overwritten by your command prompt or something? Otherwise I gotta try 3.4.4 too `:)`

Comment: @mizo, you're right, it should not work on any gcc version. I don't know why the 3 was not displayed with gcc 3.4.4 and when trying again, it sometimes appears, sometimes not, depending on the input provided. Strange...