# Parsing an equation erlang

Tags: erlang

I am learning erlang recently and I have a question.

I have an equation like this (~(2+1)).
I want to parse to polish notation? For eg.{unaryMin{add,2,1}}

How do I start?

Comment: This one should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7242955/4169859

Comment: Your example is not in polish notation as it contains an infix operation (2+1). Do you want to *convert* the expression into polish notation?

Comment: There is alot materials but I want to show as tokenizeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse something, from a simple formula to a programming language, you should start by learning about [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar), [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) and [Compiler-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler). Learning how to parse and translate/interpret something to another format is a very common task for any programmer (pretty much everything has a compiler/interpreter, even you image viewer, web browser, etc ...) so it's very important to learn about those things.

For Erlang, LYSE got a chapter about making a reverse-polish notation calculator [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/functionally-solving-problems#rpn-calculator), and for converting from an infix equation to a prefix/postfix one, you should read about [Shunt-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).
Erlang also have is own version of yacc & lex : [yecc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html), [leex](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html).